# swiper pagination bullets not shown in shadow dom

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, swiper.js

l am using swiper js in my angular application. carousal is inside the shadow dom component. but the pagination bullets not showing. what i did is

In app.component.ts

```
 selector: 'app-elem',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
    
sliderConfig: SwiperOptions = {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        slidesPerColumn: 2,
        followFinger: false,
        longSwipes: true,
        shortSwipes: true,
        spaceBetween: 15,
        slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
        updateOnWindowResize: true,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        slidesPerGroup:2,
        pagination: {
          el: '.elem-swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
          type: 'bullets',
          bulletActiveClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active,
          bulletClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet',
        },
      };
```

in app.component.html

```
<swiper [config]="sliderConfig">
  <ng-template
    swiperSlide
    *ngFor="let image of images.sliderImages"
  >
    <div
      class="bg-no-repeat bg-white bg-cover bg-center h-80w-full rounded"
      [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')' }"
    ></div>
  </ng-template>
</swiper>
<div class="elem-swiper-pagination flex justify-center my-1">
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide minimal reproducible code ?

Comment: added more information @Dev